# Exercise 7. Chapter 3. Barry Simon.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

[image]

Why 3.1.35 and 3.1.36 implies 3.1.37?

I have this: (I use $\sup(A)=c$ iff $\forall\epsilon>0\exists a\in A$: $c-a<\epsilon$)

$\sup_{F\subset I} \left(\sum_{\alpha\in F} |\beta_{\alpha}|^2\right)<\infty$
then $\forall\epsilon>0\exists \tilde{F}\subset I$ such that 
$\sup_{F\subset I} \left(\sum_{\alpha\in F} |\beta_{\alpha}|^2\right)-\sup_{\tilde{F}\subset I} \left(\sum_{\alpha\in \tilde{F}} |\beta_{\alpha}|^2\right)<\epsilon$

How could I put
$\sup_{F\subset I} \left(\sum_{\alpha\in F} |\beta_{\alpha}|^2\right)-\sup_{\tilde{F}\subset I} \left(\sum_{\alpha\in \tilde{F}} |\beta_{\alpha}|^2\right)=\sup_{G\subset I-F,G\text{ finite } }\left(\sum_{\alpha\in G} |\beta_{\alpha}|^2\right)$?

Comment: You seem to have typos - 3.3.35 and 3.3.3 should be 3.1.35 and 3.1.36.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry